# Puzzling Knight has a Message for all- Especially Newcomers

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, no-computers, chess

Of all the more than a Trillion messages he can deliver, he has especially selected this message for all.

Follow his(normal chess moves for the Knight) path to get the message.

His journey starts with D4 cell and ends in B5 cell. Of course, he can continue his message for more newcomers by hopping onto D4 again.

[image]

Comment: Full path from W to G covering all 64 squares has to be given by faithfully following Puzzling Knights path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is:

> Welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange. Enjoy your stay here. Keep on puzzling!

The path to get there is:

> **D4** F3 H4 G2 E1 D3 C5, B3 A1, C2 A3 B1, C3 A2 C1 E2 G1 H3 F2 H1, G3 E4 D2 F1 H2, G4 E3 D1 B2 A4 B6 A8 C7, D5 B4 A6 B8 C6, D8 B7 A5 C4, D6 E4 F6 D7, E5 G6 H8 F7, G5 H7 F8 E6, F4 H5, G7 F5 H6 G8 E7 C8 A7 **B5**!

Comment: Would it be possible to include the path taken to find this message?

Comment: Yes..need to show the path taken by the Knight from from W square to final square G.

Comment: I have edited to show the path.

Comment: I don’t see F4 and H5

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read the edit that said we had to use all the letters. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Congrats!  As newcomer, it is so appropriate that you got this one right..follow the knight’s message..keep on Puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

By following:

> D4-F3-H4-G2-E1-D3-C5-E6-G7-F5-H6-G8-E7-C8-A7-B5 to get Welcome P Puzzling but I’m missing a word or two in between...

Comment: You almost answered your own question..

Comment: You almost can guess the message..trick is to follow knights path to match it